# I want to redirect after complete both insert from Laravel request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

so I have this store function at my Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Penghuni::create([
        'nama_penghuni' => $request->nama_penghuni,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'phone' => $request->phone,
        'tower' => $request->tower,
        'no_unit' => $request->no_unit
    ]);

    User::create([
        'name' => $request->nama_penghuni,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        'role' => 'penghuni',
    ]);

    return redirect(route('penghuni.index'));
}
```

what I want is make sure both insert is success, because the current result I got is when Penghuni create is done but the user is fails it keeps getting redirected

hope someone can help, I use laravel 5.8

thank you

Comment: and what do you want to happen if they don't both save?

Comment: use transaction. read more https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions

Comment: @lagbox after both save success do the redirect, but now if failed for 1 table the other table insert still done, I want the redirect done when both table insert is done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This Code is Perfect check other things.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  Penghuni::create([
    'nama_penghuni' => $request->nama_penghuni,
    'email' => $request->email,
    'phone' => $request->phone,
    'tower' => $request->tower,
    'no_unit' => $request->no_unit
  ]);

  User::create([
    'name' => $request->nama_penghuni,
    'email' => $request->email,
    'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
    'role' => 'penghuni',
  ]);

  return redirect(route('penghuni.index'));
}

1. Model

Penghuni and user Model must added this Line

 protected $guarded = [];
```

> Other Solution

```
  public function store(Request $request)
 {
$penghuni = new Penghuni;
$penghuni->nama_penghuni = $request->nama_penghuni;
$penghuni->email = $request->email;
$penghuni->phone = $request->phone;
$penghuni->tower = $request->tower;
$penghuni->no_unit = $request->no_unit;
$penghuni->save();

$user = new User;
$user->name = $request->nama_penghuni;
$user->email = $request->email;
$user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
$user->role = 'role';

$penghuni->users()->save($user);

 return redirect(route('penghuni.index'));
  }
```

Comment: what is the $guarded for? I never use this kind of

Comment: The guarded attribute is the opposite of fillable attributes. In Laravel, fillable attributes are used to specify those fields which are to be mass assigned. For Fields

Comment: then what should I fill at the $guarded?

Comment: if you used $fillable than you need to fill your database filled , but you used $guarded than pass blank array it's automatic get fields

Comment: oh it solved using the $guarded on model, but how do I avoid showing querry exeption error handling page when its failed to store?

Comment: You Can use all fields validation

Comment: sorry do you mean post new question or else? this is my 1st question at stack :)

Comment: No Need to add anything , Just check  Validation

Comment: Im using validation request, how to use 2 validation request on 1 controller function? do you have any Idea?

Comment: thank you, I have solved it, using the validation request also

Comment: I already did upvote and accept, but only checkmark green not increase the upvote

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your queries in a database transaction like so:

```php
DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
    // queries here
});

return redirect(route('penghuni.index'));
```

Or something like this, depending on your use-case.

```php
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    // queries here

    // all good
    DB::commit();

    return redirect(route('penghuni.index'));
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // something went wrong
    DB::rollback();
}
```

You can read more about database transaction here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions